# Outlook mail not moving physically to another folder sometimes

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

Below is my code to move mails from inbox to another folder.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null; 
inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder destFolder = inboxFolder.Folders[somefoldername]; 
int countofmails = inboxFolder.Items.Count;           
for (int j = countofmails; j > 0; j--)
{
 Object _obj=inboxFolder.Items[j];
 if (_obj is MailItem)
  {
    MailItem mi = (MailItem)_obj;                       
    if (mi != null)
    {
     mi.SaveAs(somepath,OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
     mi.Move(destFolder);
     System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(mi);
    }
  }
}
```

This code works properly, but once in blue moon, even if the code runs successfully, the mail item is still seen in the inbox folder.

Comment: What event is triggering this code?

Comment: Is it possible a new message arrives while you are running that code?

Comment: @stuart Thomson- It is put on a schedular which is repeated every 10 minutes.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko - yes it is possible, but that one gets processed when the code runs next time. (It is put on a schedular which is repeated every 10 minutes).

Comment: I think it might be "System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(mi)" causing the problem. It might be releasing the Com object before it's actually finished with it. Try letting the garbage collector handle it and see if that helps.

Comment: @StuartThomson - thanks for your fast reply .... but i don't think so that will solve my problem.Is it that if the PC hangs that this problem will come?

Comment: It's always a possibility. How many mail items does the process handle on average? On the times it fails, are there more? Unfortunately my experience with the interop has been with new mail triggers and a restricted collection, so there's very few items being handled. Depending on how many items are in the collection, you could be hitting an Exchange imposed restriction.

Comment: @stuart thomson - i found the cause for mail not moving physically, it may not be the sole cause but now that i have found one cause i am sharing it with you-- in my code i have specified the "profile name" which is not default but the outlook instance access the default "profile name" and not the profile which i have provided to it, causing the mystery of "mail not moving physically". Do you know why outlook access default profile instead of the profile which i have mentioned?

Comment: @dmitry streblechenko- you have helped this person [link](http://microsoft.public.win32.programmer.messaging.narkive.com/hocCWW8q/outlook-object-model-oom-to-access-non-default-outlook-profile). help me too.